# Multiplication in Ruby causing overflow?

Tags: ruby, math, multiplication

So, I read that theoretically, there is no max value for integers in Ruby and that they can be as large as you want. However, when I multiply the following is resulting in a negative value (which I think is a sign of overflow?):

> > 44404051714 * 44404051714
> >     => -2081807267335685116

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Hmm, works here: `irb(main):001:0> 44404051714 * 44404051714 
=> 1971719808619586337796`

Comment: I am using irb as well - which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like a bug, either in Ruby's implementation or in the compiler used to compiler Ruby.  The value you're getting is correct modulo `2**64`.  (It's out by exactly `107 * 2**64`, to be precise.)

Comment: If you're on a fairly recent Ruby, this may be relevant: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7242

Comment: Works fine on `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [i686-darwin11.4.2], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02`

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]:`44404051714 * 44404051714
 => 1971719808619586337796 `

Comment: @hack3r: What slivu said.  What OS?  64-bit or 32-bit?  Which compiler was used to compile Ruby, with what options?

Comment: @hack3r, could be something with your installed version. how did you install it? on what platform? [**here is a proof**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=multiplication-in-ruby-causing-overflow.rb&versions=*&run=true) it is running correctly on all rubies all versions, on a 64 bit CentOS

Comment: @silvu: Mac OS X 10.8, 64 bit. I installed it using MacPorts. I think you guys are right. This might be a compilation issue

Comment: @hack3r:  Yep, that definitely smells like Clang's work, then. :-)

Comment: @hack3r:  See http://bugs.python.org/issue12973 for what happened when some of Python's integer arithmetic met Clang. A very similar issue to this one. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I love how [the ticket at llvm](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10923) took all of five minutes from "Please, fix. :)" to "Fix _your_ code".

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in Ruby's implementation of multiplication for the `Fixnum` class. Looking at the source, the following lines (heavily snipped) from the `fixmul` function in [numeric.c](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/entry/numeric.c#L2667) jump out as suspicious:

```
...
2645:   long a, b;
...
2663:   c = a * b;
2664:   r = LONG2FIX(c);
...
2667:   if (FIX2LONG(r) != c || c/a != b) {
2668:       r = rb_big_mul(rb_int2big(a), rb_int2big(b));
...
```

If I'm reading it correctly, that's from the code that's doing `Fixnum` multiplication, and the bit of the code that's supposed to be doing overflow detection to figure out if the result should actually be recomputed as a `Bignum`.  The trouble is that it's bad C code:  `a` and `b` have type long, and if `a * b` overflows that produces undefined behaviour according to the C standard.  A good compiler can make use of this by assuming that overflow never happens in a correct C program, and based on that logic can optimize away the overflow check `c / a != b`.

So if your version of Ruby is compiled with a reasonably recent compiler (a recent version of Clang would be a good example), that could be what's causing this.

At any rate, I think it's worth a bug report:  even if this isn't the cause of what you're seeing, the C code above is suspicious.

---

EDIT: Daniel Fischer points out in the comments that there's a `volatile long c` declaration.  In theory, this should prevent the overflow check from being optimized away.  So if that *is* the cause of the issue, then this would make it a compiler bug rather than a bug in Ruby's code.

Comment: You are right - I will file a bug report. Also, it appears to be an issue on my machine only. I tried a bunch of online interpreters and it seemed to work fine there. Which makes me believe this might truly be a bug

Comment: It could also be a compiler bug, or an indication that Ruby wasn't built with the correct compiler flags for your machine.  There have been similar issues with Python in the past if the '-fwrapv' option to gcc wasn't used.

Comment: The declaration `volatile long c;` would forbid the elimination of the `c / a != b` check, so if it is eliminated, it's a bug in the C compiler.

Comment: @DanielFischer: And I see that they're using a `volatile` declaration (for `a` and `b`) on HP machines.

Comment: Ah, whoops.  And they're already using `volatile long c`.  Good point.  Maybe this *is* a compiler bug then.